# How can I make a template that Notepad++ uses every time I make a new document?

Tags: templates, plugins, notepad++

So I was wondering, how can I make Notepad++ automatically have a little bit of code written for me when starting a new document.

I heard that I can use a plugin called "NewFileBrowser" for this but I don't quite understand how the plugin works.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can create a template, save it `whateverYouWant.tpl` then open it when you need and save it with new name.

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the answer, but is it possible to have that template open up on every new document?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could ask Npp forum: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/online-help/